# Apple Retina display doesn't detect headphone

Tags: macos, mac, audio

Here is my setup:

I have a MBP 15 Retina Display with a Thunderbolt monitor connected to it.

I have a specific set of earphones (IEMs) which aren't being detected by the audio out port.
Despite having them plugged in I am unable to get the Thunderbolt to stop playing the sound.
The above earphones don't change the status of the Sound Pref. pane.

I have another set of earphones which are detected just fine. These do change the Sound Pref. pane to reflect headphones.

The earphones mentioned in case #1 work fine on an iPhone and don't have a Mic built-in.

How do I get the headphones to detect is there a way to force audio out of the Mac with the first earphones plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the pplug has a tiny misform which leads to a malformed detection, try using a 2.5 jack to 2.5 jack adapter plug, they cost a buck or 2 and might jsut do the trick.